# How to send XML file to another server using network?

Tags: c#, web-services, webrequest

I have a xml file and I want to send it to another server using net work.
So I write below code

```
private string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
    string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    return ret;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;

    try
    {
        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~\\client-authentication.xml");
        string uri = "http://10.3.4.84/";
        req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";        
        req.ContentType = "text/xml\r\n"; 
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
        writer.Close();

        rsp = req.GetResponse(); 
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
    }
}
```

but is doesn't work.What is the wrong?
How to sent "client-authentication.xml" file?

Comment: What does not work? You are not receiving a file at all? empty file? error message?

Comment: What happens when it "doesn't work"? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: there is no error. but sever response is wrong what I expect. It always return default page.

Comment: Looks like your server is local , so do you get get the XML content at the server? YOur response would depend on how you have written your server code.